# How to enable Server choosing on PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm running XAMPP on my local host, and i want phpmyadmin to add another field of server on login page, so i can manage an external mysql server as well..

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the phpMyAdmin config file add another configuration block, the file in question is config.inc.php , make sure that before the new configuration block you do `$i++;`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty easy. Just add another block of code for the second server.

The configuration starts at: `$i++;`
The configuration ends before: `// If you have more than one server configured...`

Just copy and paste that (make sure you include `$i++`), and change the settings to the new server.

Answer (score -3):

You need to adjust the configuration of the mysql server you want to connect to so it allows connecting from the outside.

I suggest you use [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to administrate your mysql server(s).

Comment: phpmyadmin allows you to do this easily and shows a drop down on the login screen when there are multiple servers in your config, so should be very much possible without hacking any core code.